# PHP Regex Pattern To Match Emoji Unicode

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I am using this pattern in

`preg_match_all( "/'s|'t|'re|'ve|'m|'ll|'d| ?\p{L}+| ?\p{N}+| ?[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+|\s+(?!\S)|\s+/", $text, $matches );`

to tokenize my `$text` variable content...

`$text` variable contains : `"Hello!! I'm Sajjad Hossain Sagor. It's 2023. w00t :D \ud83e\udd17"`

Here `\ud83e\udd17` this is encoded emoji unicode of  which i want to capture as one match... but using the above pattern it matches these unicodes seperately...

see below output...

```
array (size=23)
  0 => string 'Hello' (length=5)
  1 => string '!!' (length=2)
  2 => string ' I' (length=2)
  3 => string ''m' (length=2)
  4 => string ' Sajjad' (length=7)
  5 => string ' Hossain' (length=8)
  6 => string ' Sagor' (length=6)
  7 => string '.' (length=1)
  8 => string ' It' (length=3)
  9 => string ''s' (length=2)
  10 => string ' 2023' (length=5)
  11 => string '.' (length=1)
  12 => string ' w' (length=2)
  13 => string '00' (length=2)
  14 => string 't' (length=1)
  15 => string ' :' (length=2)
  16 => string 'D' (length=1)
  17 => string ' \' (length=2)
  18 => string 'ud' (length=2)
  19 => string '83' (length=2)
  20 => string 'e' (length=1)
  21 => string '\' (length=1)
  22 => string 'udd' (length=3)
  23 => string '17' (length=2)
```

how to capture these unicodes as one capture modifying the above pattern!! Thanks!!

Comment: To figure the emoji you are speaking about in a PHP string, you have to write something like `$text = "blablubli \u{1F917} blablubla";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
(?:\\u[a-f0-9]+)+|'[stdm]|'[rv]e|'ll| ?\p{L}+| ?\p{N}+| ?(?!\\u[a-f0-9]+\b)[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+|\s+(?!\S)|\s+
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/ok5Te) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g2Cg1X/1).

```
$text = "Hello!! I'm Sajjad Hossain Sagor. It's 2023. w00t :D \ud83e\udd17";
$pattern = "/(?:\\\\u[a-f0-9]+)+|'[stdm]|'[rv]e|'ll| ?\p{L}+| ?\p{N}+| ?(?!\\\\u[a-f0-9]+\b)[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+|\s+(?!\S)|\s+/";
preg_match_all(
    $pattern,
    $text, 
    $matches
);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
array(19) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "!!"
  [2]=>
  string(2) " I"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "'m"
  [4]=>
  string(7) " Sajjad"
  [5]=>
  string(8) " Hossain"
  [6]=>
  string(6) " Sagor"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "."
  [8]=>
  string(3) " It"
  [9]=>
  string(2) "'s"
  [10]=>
  string(5) " 2023"
  [11]=>
  string(1) "."
  [12]=>
  string(2) " w"
  [13]=>
  string(2) "00"
  [14]=>
  string(1) "t"
  [15]=>
  string(2) " :"
  [16]=>
  string(1) "D"
  [17]=>
  string(1) " "
  [18]=>
  string(12) "\ud83e\udd17"
}
```