# Filter emojis in PHP from javascript string

Tags: php, regex, emoji

My setup: I store text that was parsed/filtered with javascript in a database and read the stored text with PHP. When I try to filter the text to get rid of emojis but fail at this task - even with some libaries and code I found online. I guess it has something to do with the way the string is interpreted and that it was stored in a js encoded way.
(btw: I don't want to get rid of all uncode characters, just the emojis)

Let's take a look at this string (emoji is supposed to be devil)

```
$text = "foo \ud83d\ude08 bar";
```

When I try to filter it with something like this it won't work

```
$result = preg_replace('/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u', '', $text);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and a minimal reproduction? It would be useful in helping you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Regex Pattern To Match Emoji Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75582202/php-regex-pattern-to-match-emoji-unicode)

Comment: @beerwin what do you need? There is an example string (that's what is read from the db) and a code to filter it. Ofc I can put it into one box but there shouldn't be more needed.

shingo No, it just catches the emoji as one matchbut I still don't see a way to remove it.

Comment: @Insomnia88 There is also a very simplistic approach of having a list of emojis which you want to remove. It doesn't need to be fancy coding just to filter out something, especially if it has undesired side-effects. However this is not a very performant approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to successfully filter out emojis from the string, you'll need to make sure that the encoding is consistent between JavaScript and PHP. One possible solution is to convert the JavaScript-encoded string to its corresponding Unicode representation before storing it in the database. This way, when you retrieve the string with PHP, it will be easier to manipulate and filter out the emojis.

Use json_decode function to decode the JavaScript-encoded string into its Unicode representation

```
$text = 'foo \ud83d\ude08 bar';
$decoded_text = json_decode('["' . $text . '"]');
$filtered_text = preg_replace('/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u', '', $decoded_text[0]);

echo $filtered_text;
```

Comment: thanks, this way of decoding the string was the detail I was looking for.